# how to prevent duplicate peripherals in corebletooth?

Tags: swift4, core-bluetooth

I am new to Corebluetooth. I want to prevent duplicate peripherals when scanning. Can anyone help me?
And one more question, how to connect peripheral with in range ?

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) 
 {
    if (peripheral.name != nil) && (peripheral.name == "EXP") || 
  (peripheral.name == "EXP") 
      {


        let key = peripheral.identifier.uuidString
        let data = advertisementData.description

        if let previous = datas[key]
        {
            if (previous != data)
            {
                print("Different \(String(describing: peripheral.name)): \ . (data)")
            }
        } else
        {
            print("\(String(describing: peripheral.name)): \(data)");
            datas[key] = data
        }

            peripherals.append(peripheral)
        lblDeviceCount.isHidden = false
        lblDeviceCount.text = "\(peripherals.count) Devices Found"

            tblPeriPheral.reloadData()
     }

}
```

Comment: Why using `description` in `let data = advertisementData.description` You won't be able to retrieve data later from it. Also, what are your scanning options?

Comment: thanks for reply, ok then how to remove duplicate values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop to prevent duplicate peripherals. If new peripheral has an identifier equal to an existing peripheral in peripherals (the variable you are using) then don't append it to peripherals.

```
for existing in peripherals {
    if existing.identifier == peripheral.identifier { return }
}
```

For the second part, you should read about [RSSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication), it will help you know whether you're closer or far from the device. Depending on the range you can make decision whether to connect to it or not.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't prevent duplicates, as `identifier` is not a stable ID. Apple is inventing a new identifier for the same peripheral every now and then, for privacy reasons.